# URL HTMLCLient calls in Android

Tags: android, http, url, android-webview, androidhttpclient

I'm working with an API which requires me to make "URL HTMLCLient calls" and it returns a data in JSON format. I've tested the links on my browser and they work fine but when I try to retrieve the data in Android I keep getting a null value back.

Here is my code below

```
public String callWebservice(String weblink) {

String result = "";

    try {

        //String link = "http://free.worldweatheronline.com/feed/weather.ashx?q=cardiff&num_of_days=4&format=json&key=eb9390089uhq175307132201";
        URL url = new URL(weblink);

        URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                urlc.getInputStream()));
        result = bfr.readLine();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        result = "timeout";
    }
    return result;
}
```

The weblink holds the url I'm trying to retrieve info, I have tested the code with the worldweatheronline JSON API and it works fine. My question here would be does the fact that the API docs have said to make URL HTMLClient calls require me to do this in a different way from a regular HTTP request if not then what could be the possible reason I am getting a null value back when the same link works fine on my broswer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are not appending buffered output after the URL call.

This your updated code:

```
public String callWebservice() {
        String result = "", line = "";

        try {

            String weblink = "http://itwillbealright.co.uk/dev1/camc/clientmethod.php?method=Login&id=&version=&username=m&password=m";
            URL url = new URL(weblink);

            URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
            BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    urlc.getInputStream()));

            while ((line = bfr.readLine()) != null) {
                result += line;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            result = "timeout";
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: I've tried both solutions and still get null. There seems to be an exception when I get to this line of code result = bfr.readLine()

Comment: Please post the logcat output if there is any exception.

Comment: It's a nullpointer so I'm still getting a null value from the API. Could this be related to any headers?

Comment: I don't think so. Url is same as you commented in your code or it is different?

Comment: From my Async Task in my Activity

Comment: Ok...well I tried your code in AsyncTask and it is working fine for me.

Comment: There is nothing in log no error, the code runs fine but returns null. Can you please send me the project where you have done this? I must be missing something. Or I can send you mine

Comment: Is it "null" or blank string ?

Comment: Yes for the previous URL I am getting same result as browser but for your updated one it is coming blank.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

// Somewhere in your code this is called
// in a thread which is not the user interface
// thread

```
try {
  URL url = new URL("http://www.vogella.com");
  HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url
    .openConnection();
  readStream(con.getInputStream());
  } catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}



private void readStream(InputStream in) {
  BufferedReader reader = null;
  try {
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    String line = "";
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(line);
    }
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } finally {
    if (reader != null) {
      try {
        reader.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
  }
}
```